# Why doesn't my struct code doesn't work well?

Tags: c

This is sample code..
But Code doesn't work...
Here are some code and screenshot of my project.
In this code, the result is

Location of RED BALL
(3,4)

```
#include <stdio.h>
char copy_str(char *dest, char *src);
int Print_Obj_Status(struct obj OBJ);
 struct obj{
  char name[20];
  int x, y;
  } Ball;

int main(){
Ball.x = 3;
Ball.y = 4;
copy_str(Ball.name, "RED BALL");

Print_Obj_Status(Ball);

return 0;
 }

int Print_Obj_Status(struct obj OBJ) {
   printf("Location of %s \n", OBJ.name);
   printf("( %d, %d ) \n", OBJ.x, OBJ.y);

   return 0;
 }
char copy_str(char *dest, char *src){
while (*src){
    *dest = *src;
    src++;
    dest++;
 }

*dest = '\0';

return 1;
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Indent your code properly before posting

Comment: have you tried defining the struct before defining the functions

Comment: Hi ! Here are some comments, since the question has already been answered by Anthony B.

- Your code is not very easy to read, so you should indent it. Everyone will be able to understand it in a few seconds if you do that !

- You should use a terminal (you seem to be using a Mac, so it has a zsh terminal by default). An IDE can help you (I recommend VSCode), but you should compile your projects in your terminal. It's much easier (in my opinion) to read errors, warnings and outputs in a terminal.

P.S. : @klutt, it doesn't cost much to be polite !

Comment: After reading your code, you seem to not have declared a Ball variable, and yet you're trying to access one of its fields with 'Ball.x'.

Comment: @EliasALICHE: `Ball` is defined in the declaration starting in line 4 and ending in lnie 7. If it had not been declared, the messages would have been different.

Answer (score 1):

The function declaration `int Print_Obj_Status(struct obj OBJ);` declares `struct obj` only inside the function declaration. At the end of the declaration, that `struct obj` is no longer known for purposes of compiling later code. That is what the first message is warning you about.

Then this code:

```
struct obj{
  char name[20];
  int x, y;
  } Ball;
```

defines a new `struct obj` type. Because the previous `struct obj` is no longer known, this is a new type, even though it has the same name.

Later, when you call the function, in `Print_Obj_Status(Ball);`, you are passing it an object, `Ball`, of the later type `struct obj`, but the function was declared to take a different type, the earlier `struct obj`. Even though they have the same name, they were declared in different scopes and are different types. So the compiler gives you an error because the function is not being passed the type it was declared with.

The same problem happens with the function definition; `int Print_Obj_Status(struct obj OBJ)`; the function is defined to have a parameter of the new type, which is different from the old type.

To fix this, put the definition of the structure first. Then, in the declaration `int Print_Obj_Status(struct obj OBJ);`, there is already a `struct obj` in scope. When `struct obj` appears in this form (without a following `{` that starts a structure definition) and there is already a declaration of `struct obj` in scope, it refers to the visible declaration instead of creating a new one. Then `Print_Obj_Status` will be declared to have a parameter of the same type as the type it is later called with and later defined with.

Answer (score 0):

Move the struct definition before the function definition:

```
struct obj{
    char name[20];
    int x, y;
} Ball;

int Print_Obj_Status(struct obj OBJ);
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler complains because `struct obj` is not yet declared when it reaches the declaration of `Print_Obj_Status`. This is easily solved by placing the struct declaration before the function declaration. Also, the function doesn't need to return a value and you don't need to declare your own string copy function. If you include the header `string.h` you can use `strcpy`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct obj {
    char name[20];
    int x, y;
} Ball;

void Print_Obj_Status(struct obj OBJ)
{
    printf("Location of %s \n", OBJ.name);
    printf("( %d, %d ) \n", OBJ.x, OBJ.y);
}

int main(void)
{
    Ball.x = 3;
    Ball.y = 4;
    strcpy(Ball.name, "RED BALL");
    Print_Obj_Status(Ball);
    return 0;
}
```